# Static/dynamic libraries vs .so libaries?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, dll

I come from a windows w/ visual-studio background for native development and I am now going to compile native code for use on android.

I am not sure how the unix-like libraries (.so?) work. Are they static (like a .lib on windows) or dynamically loaded like a DLL? 
For example, in visual studio, I add the .lib file to my project for compiling, and then load the .dll during runtime. What is the equivalent in unix-stuff, say by using GCC?

Thanks!

Comment: they are dynamic (shared objects) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Naming.

Comment: So you don't need a .lib equivalent for compiling in unix development, just load the dynamic library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux, the .so files are the equivalent(*) of the .dll files on Windows, in the sense that they are loaded dynamically to the executable when it is executed. Note however that you don't need a .lib file when linking your application. The linker will find the information directly in the .so file.

*: There are differences.

Comment: The main one I can think of is that the Linux .so file can have undefined dependencies. They'll be solved at runtime. (On Windows, they need to be solved at link time.)

Comment: Also, Linux .so files do not have a DllEntry function that is called when the dynamic library is loaded/unloaded by the executable.

Comment: What do you mean by undefined? You can always create a fake `lib` file for something that doesn't exist, and the program will run if it finds that `DLL` when it's started...

Answer (score 2):

First, you should read a page on [Static, Shared Dynamic and Loadable Linux Libraries](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html).

That should clarify several of your questions. That page has source code examples which are nice for beginners.

Another interesting reference is [Writing DLLs for Linux apps](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-dll/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

.so files on Linux act the same way as .dll on Windows and .dylib on Mac OSX.